# Count subsets whose cardinalities are congruent to 0, 1 and 2 modulo 3 respectively

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Given a set of N elements, compute the number of subsets whose cardinalities are congruent to 0, 1 and 2 modulo 3 respectively.

Any hints would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to evaluate
 \begin{align}a_N=\binom N0+\binom N3+\binom N6+\binom N9+\cdots,\\b_N=\binom N1+\binom N4+\binom N7+\binom N{10}+\cdots,\\c_N=\binom N2+\binom N5+\binom N8+\binom N{11}+\cdots.\end{align}
 Note that, if $x^3=1$, then
 \begin{align} (1+x)^N&=\binom N0+\binom N1x+\binom N2x^2+\binom N3x^3+\binom N4x^4+\binom N5x^5+\cdots\\&=\binom N0+\binom N1x+\binom N2x^2+\binom N3+\binom N4x+\binom N5x^2+\cdots\\&=a_N+b_Nx+c_Nx^2.\end{align}
 So write down the equation
 \begin{align}a_N+xb_N+x^2c_N=(1+x)^N\end{align}
 with $x$ replaced in turn with each of the three cube roots of unity, and solve the resulting system of three linear equations for the three unknowns $a_N, b_N, c_N$.

The cube roots of unity are $1$, $\omega=\cos\frac{2\pi}3+i\sin\frac{2\pi}3$, and $\omega^2=\bar\omega$, so the equations are
$$a_N+b_N+c_N=2^N;$$
$$a_N+\omega b_N+\omega^2c_N=(1+\omega)^N;$$
$$a_N+\omega^2b_N+\omega c_N=(1+\bar\omega)^N.$$
To solve for $a_N$ we add all the equations and divide by $3$; since $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$ we get
$$a_N=\frac{2^N+(1+\omega)^N+(1+\bar\omega)^N}3=\frac{2^N+2\Re(1+\omega)^N}3.$$
Since $(1+\omega)^N=(\cos\frac\pi3+i\sin\frac\pi3)^N=\cos\frac{N\pi}3+i\sin\frac{N\pi}3$, this simplifies to
$$a_N=\frac{2^N+2\cos\frac{N\pi}3}3.$$
In like manner, we get
$$b_N=\frac{2^N-\cos\frac{N\pi}3+\sqrt{3}\sin\frac{N\pi}3}3$$
and
$$c_N=\frac{2^N-\cos\frac{N\pi}3-\sqrt{3}\sin\frac{N\pi}3}3.$$

**Alternatively,** use Pascal's identity $\binom Nk=\binom{N-1}k+\binom{N-1}{k-1}$ to derive the linear recurrences $a_N=a_{N-1}+c_{N-1},b_N=b_{N-1}+a_{N-1},c_N=c_{N-1}+b_{N-1}$ with initial values $a_0=1,b_0=c_0=0$. As an alternative to the matrix method, you could use the guess-and-check method: calculate a few values, observe the simple pattern, and verify by induction.

Comment: I don't know why, but `$$ <math> $$` notation doesn't work well with spoiler markers. To bypass that, you can use `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}`, but be sure that the whole equation source is in one line (these wraps automatically). Also, `align` environment is great for multiple-line formulas and derivations, just as those in your post. Please check if my edit matches your intentions.

Comment: I only fixed a typo.

Comment: Well, I finally solved it. Thou it took some tiresome work with equation solving, covered a good two pages.
$$
s_0=\frac{2^N+(-ω)^N+(-ω^2)^N}{3}
$$
$$
s_1=\frac{2^N-(-ω)^{N+1}-(-ω^2)^{N+1}}{3}
$$
$$
s_2=\frac{2^N+(-ω)^{N+2}+(-ω^2)^{N+2}}{3}
$$
Where ω a primitive third root of unity. I guess there must exist a more delicate solution to it without having to go through all the paper work but I couldn't figure it out without brute force. If you have a more delicate solution it would be interesting. But anyway, thanks for the help, it was appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\binom{N}{3k}$ , $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\binom{N}{3k+1}$
and $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\binom{N}{3k+2}$ respectively.

This under the convention that $\binom{n}{k}=0$ if $k\notin\left\{ 0,\dots,n\right\} $.

Comment: Wow, I thought Snape was asking for advice on how to evaluate those sums in closed form. Your interpretation didn't even occur to me. By the way, how do I do spoiler protection here? I thought the "!" would do it, but I must be doing something wrong because it didn't work.

Comment: @bof Well. OP would appreciate any hint and at the moment I am too lazy to go for chasing closed forms. What do you mean by 'spoiler protection'? That term is new to me (I am Dutch).

Comment: What I meant was, I wanted to set up the elaborate hint so that it would not be visible unless one hovers with the mouse, in order not to spoil the problem for Snape in case he really only wanted a hint.

Comment: I did also come up with something similar: $\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor N/3 \rfloor} \binom{n}{3k}$, $\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor N/3 \rfloor} \binom{n}{3k+1}$, $\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor N/3 \rfloor} \binom{n}{3k+2}$. Shouldn't $k = \{0,2,3,...,\lfloor N/3 \rfloor\}$?
After that I'm stuck. How do I get the closed form? And does that lead to the same conclution as bof?
\Snape

Comment: The convention mentioned in my answer makes somehow free from the restrictions on $k$. It is the same idea as yours and of bof. Are you capable of exploiting the answer of bof? Setting $z:=e^{\frac{2}{3}\pi i}=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}i\sqrt{3}$
it provides you a way to find closed expressions for $a_{N}$, $b_{N}$
and $c_{N}$ in $z$.

Comment: Sorry, I know this is an old question, but could someone explain how dhrab's hint could be used??