# Number of Subsets of {1,2,3,...n} with number of elements congruent to r modulo 3

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find the total number of subsets of $\{1, 2, 3, 4, \ldots, n\}$ with number of elements congruent to $r$ modulo $3$? Answer should not be with summations.

Attempt: For $r=1$ summation answer is ${n \choose 1} + {n \choose 4} + {n \choose 7} + \cdots$

Depending on whether $n$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $3$ we can terminate the summation. We can proceed for $r=2, 3$.

Also I found this [Count subsets whose cardinalities are congruent to 0, 1 and 2 modulo 3 respectively](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/787608/count-subsets-whose-cardinalities-are-congruent-to-0-1-and-2-modulo-3-respectiv)

I don't understand how I could get a recurrence here for $r=1$, $a_n = a_{n-1} + ???$. Also some hint on solving the recurrence equation. Would prefer any type of combinatoial proof if possible.I am an undergrad of non math major. I use How to count Slomson as reference.

Comment: The question that you link to is the same one and has a full solution provided.  Do you need to use recurrence relations?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, need to use a combinatorial proof if possible. It need not be recurrence relation. Edited the question.