# number of $k$-subsets of an $n$ element set, where $k \equiv 1 \bmod 3$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, congruences

I would like to find the number of $k$-subsets of an $n$ element set, where $k \equiv 1\bmod 3$.

We can consider the set $[n]=\{1,2, \ldots, n\}$. The number I am looking for would be

$$\sum_{j\geq 0} \binom{n}{3j+1}.$$

Is there a well known closed formula for this sum? Thank you!

Comment: $$\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom n{3j+1}=\frac{2^n-\cos\frac{n\pi}3+\sqrt{3}\sin\frac{n\pi}3}3$$

Comment: $$\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom n{3j+1}=\frac{2^n+d_n}3$$ where $$(d_0,d_1,d_2,\dots)=(-1,+1,+2,+1,-1,-2,-1,+1,+2,+1,-1,-2,-1,+1,+2,+1,-1,-2,\dots)$$

Answer (score 1):

[Count subsets whose cardinalities are congruent to 0, 1 and 2 modulo 3 respectively](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/787608/count-subsets-whose-cardinalities-are-congruent-to-0-1-and-2-modulo-3-respectiv)
(couldn't put this as comment because I don't have sufficient reputation).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using complex number. For instance, let

$$P(x)=(1+x)^n$$

then

$$\sum_{j\geq 0}\binom{n}{3j+1}=\frac{1}{3}\left(\omega^2P(\omega)+\omega P(\omega^2)+2^n\right)$$ where $\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}=-\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{3}$.